# How do I check if date occurs today?

Tags: mysql

Here's what I have.

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN 
DATE_FORMAT(a.lastLogin, 'W') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), 'W') 
THEN 'Today' 
ELSE 
DATE_FORMAT(a.lastLogin, 'W') 
END AS lastlogin
FROM authors a
```

I am pretty sure there is a much simpler way to do this that I'm missing.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`DATE(a.lastlogin) = DATE(NOW())`

the `DATE()` function normalizes a datetime column to just the date portion (e.g. `2009-11-16 16:45:23` would become just `2009-11-16`)